# How to find the second largest value with Pascal

Tags: pascal

I have a Problem to Show the second largest value.

Here is the Code

```
program testeFeldZweitMax (input, output);
{ testet die Funktion FeldZweitMax }

const
  FELDGROESSE = 10;

type
  tIndex = 1..FELDGROESSE;
  tFeld = array [tIndex] of integer;

var 
  Feld : tFeld;
  i : integer;

function FeldZweitMax (var inFeld : tFeld) : integer;
var
  Maximum: integer;
  j : tIndex;
begin
  Maximum := inFeld[1];
  for j := 2 to FELDGROESSE  do
    if inFeld[j] > Maximum then
      Maximum := inFeld[j];
  FeldZweitMax := Maximum
end;

begin { Testprogramm }
  writeln('Bitte geben Sie ', FELDGROESSE, ' Zahlen ein:');
  for i := 1 to FELDGROESSE do
    read (Feld [i]);
  writeln('Die zweitgroesste Zahl ist ', FeldZweitMax (Feld), '.');
end. { testeFeldZweitMax }
```

As you can see the Code Show me only the largest value. I Need some help with showing the second largest value.

```
var
  Maximum, ZweitMax: integer;
  j : tIndex;
begin
  Maximum := inFeld[1];   
  ZweitMax := inFeld[2];
  for j := 1 to FELDGROESSE do
  begin
    if inFeld[j] < Maximum then
      inFeld[j] := Maximum;
    Maximum := ZweitMax;
    ZweitMax := inFeld[j]; 
    FeldZweitMax := ZweitMax
  end
end;
```

It doesn't work perfectly. Some suggestions for me?

Comment: You always equate feldzweitmax to the maximum. Is that logical? Then it always be the same. The key is finding about /when/ Maximum contains the value you  want and expanding the if with a begin end block.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Yes i know, that in this case i always equate the Maximum. That's why i Need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that you have (at some point) the values `Maximum > ZweitMax` (f.ex. 5 and 2 respectively).
The next value (x) to evaluate might be

- a)  x > Maximum
- b)  x > ZweitMax (but less than Maximum)
- c)  x < ZweitMax

In case a) Maximum should become x and ZweitMax should become previous Maximum

In case b) Maximum should remain and ZweitMax should become x

In case c) no change to Maximum and ZweitMax (IOW, no action required)

A couple of hints:

- Initialize both Maximum and ZweitMax to the smallest possible value (according to the type) before you start to evaluate the actual inputted values.
- In case a) set ZweitMax to previous Maximum before assigning the new value to Maximum.

Comment: *.. and Maximum to ZweitMax + 1 before you start..*. What if all input values are at the lowest level?

Comment: @LURD Good point! Actually both values should be at minimum. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: Kudos for explaining the logic rather than just writing the code. That would be worthy of a second upvote if I could give one.

Comment: Thanks @Ken I sensed a scent of homework and therefore did not include any code.